# Highstock => getting issue of type error on initial load of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

i am using highcharts in react js and when it loads first time in browser it give error
i don't know what am doing wrong which data i am not passing on initial load of stock chart

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at h.d.updateData (highstock.js:413)
    at main.js:328
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23488)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3946)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3995)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4057)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23575)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11277)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23448)
```

and when i reload the page everything works fine

initially i am providing these options to highchart

```
title: {
    text: 'chart',
    align: 'left',
    style: { fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontWeight: 500, fontSize: 20 }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%b %e',
      week: '%e. %b',
      month: '%b \'%y'
    },
    events: {
      setExtremes: function (e) {
        $.each(this.series, (index, obj) => {
          obj.options.dataGrouping.units = [['day', [1]]];
        });
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
    className: 'highcharts-color-0',
    title: {
      text: 'Amount($)'
    },
    opposite: false
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Net Profit',
    data: [0],
    dataGrouping: {
      units: [['day', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Units Sold',
    data: [0],
    dataGrouping: {
      units: [['day', [1]]]
    }
  }],
  lang: {
    noData: "No data To Display"
  },
  noData: {
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: '#303030'
    }
  }
```

Comment: please provide codesandbox for validating

Comment: thank you for reaching the issue is resolved series of highchart was getting updated in useEffect with null value on initial load that was causing the issue.